# unable to give space between two rows using margin- top and botton in aspx

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have four `<tr>` elements . I want to add space between all four rows vertically. How can I add spaces using css?

```
 <table>
      <tr style="margin-bottom:5px">
          <td> Companies </td>
          <td> : </td>
          <td>
              <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCompanies" Width="200px">
                  <asp:ListItem Text="Dell Pvt Ltd" />
              </asp:DropDownList>
          </td>
      </tr>

      <tr style="margin-top:5px">
          <td> Quotations </td>
          <td> : </td>
          <td>
              <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlQuotations" Width="200px">
                  <asp:ListItem Text="Q1" />
              </asp:DropDownList>
          </td>
      </tr>
  <table>
```

Comment: Use padding on your td's

Comment: Use <table cellspacing="5px">. This is old and deprecated but still works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `border-spacing` css property on your table:

```
table {border-spacing: 0 10px;}
```

The above will add 10px between your rows

[More information about border-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing)

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9a1kdfz8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `display: block` on `<tr>`
html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding : 8px 12px;
}

tr {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

demo : http://codepen.io/gauravsam/pen/jWZPeg

Comment: do this and your columns won't line up anymore if your content isn't exactly the same: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgaJmJ